# Thread 1: Breakpoint 4.1 error when i press a button which is modal to another view controller

Tags: ios

Hello this code is preventing the simulator to run the app, though it says there are no issues and Build succeeded but pressing Play Game button ends up with this error.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
@autoreleasepool {


    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
 }
}
```

and it says Thread 1:breakpoint 4.1 Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why is your post body starting with a verb?! Topics are not supposed to be half of sentences to be continued in the body!! Edit your post and put a proper topic and explanation for it.

Answer (score 0):

i think you put BreakPoints to deactivate them goto Debug--> Deactivate BreakPoints or simply press command+Y

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error
check out the view controller
you might be checking some values in log so it is a breakpoint initialised.
Drag the mouse over breakpoint inside to code screen
[image]